# how to send from data using get method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

search view ->
admincp is controller and search is method.

```
 <?php
 echo form_open('admincp/search');
 $data = array('name' => 'search', );
 echo form_input($data);
 $data4 = array( 'name' => 'submit',);
  echo form_submit($data4);
  echo  form_close(); ?>
```

suppose I search for `abc` then I want that it send me to this url `admincp/search/abc`

Comment: Catch the submit event of form, and redirect the window to your URL

Comment: but I want to only use Codeigniter. is there any function to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can add jquery event.

- On form submit
- Get text field value
- set new url and append that searched value
- Something like `url/search/abc`
- and redirect to this new url

Answer (score 0):

So the overall idea is:

1. Catch the form submission via `onsubmit` event, [know more](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)
2. Now take out the value which user submitted in your event function
3. Use Codeigniter `base_url` function to create a GET url with search query appended to it [See about base_url()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url)
4. Now redirect the user window to that particular URL using `Window.location`, [see more](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_window_location.asp?output=print.Location.ThePagePagePagePagePage)

A sample code is given below, you might need to tweak it a bit:

```
<?php
$attributes = array('onsubmit' => 'return makeGET(this);');
echo form_open('admincp/search', $attributes);
$data = array('name' => 'search', 'id' => 'query');
echo form_input($data);
$data4 = array( 'name' => 'submit',);
echo form_submit($data4);
echo  form_close();


<script>
var makeGET = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = document.getElementById('query');
    var url = "<?php echo base_url('admincp/search/');" + query;
    window.location = url;
}
</script>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the default method is for submitting forms is `POST` for a good reason. But I'll assume you want users to be able to bookmark these searches which is why you want to use `GET`.

All that is needed is to set the "method" of the form. (Note: I'm using the quick way to define an array. `['method'=>'get']` is the same as `array('method'=>'get')` but with less typing.)

```
 echo form_open('admincp/search', ['method'=>'get']);
```

When the form is submitted `Admincp::search()` will be called but it will use a query string and not the nice CodeIgniter URL format. In other words, instead of `admincp/search/abc` it will be `controller/method?search=abc`. But that will bookmark just fine.

If you must have the `admincp/search/abc` URL then you will have to use JavaScript as the other answers have shown.

The rest of your form HTML could be a little cleaner too. You're making more work than you need to.

```
 echo form_input('search');  // name of the input

 // No field name is provided to `form_submit()` so 
 // it won't be part of the query string.
 echo form_submit('', 'Submit'); 
 echo form_close();
```

Note the closing php tag (`?>`) has been removed.
DO NOT use PHP close tags at the end of a .php file!!!

To process the data from the submit,
define the following function in the `Admincp` controller.

```
public function search()
{
    //get value from "search" field of form
    $search = $this->input->get('search'); 
    // code that uses search criteria
    // and then displays search results
}
```

The query string value is captured by using the `input` library. Specifically, by using the `get()` method. Read about the Input Class [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).